# PHP :unable to check if a form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am using a form in php file inside a modal window like this

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                <form  method="post" action="m.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lable>Name</lable>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lable>Email</lable>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lable>Details</lable>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <lable>Message</lable>
                        <textarea name="" id=""  class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" style=" background: #eee; width:100px;display: block;margin-left:auto;">Submit</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

file name is **m.php** now when i press the submit button it doesn't detect form submission

```
<?php

if( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
    die("form submitted");
}

?>
```

i tried `$_POST['submit']` as well kindly help me whats wrong with it

Answer (score 5):

This is because you dont press a submit button, you press a link called submit. Try replacing it with `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`.

Also, your check wether your form has been submitted uses a dangerous method. If you have multiple forms to be handled in your code, it will catch them all. A better approach would be:

```
if( isset($_POST['nameOfSubmitbutton']) ){}
// because you can now easily do:
if( isset($_POST['completelyDifferentButton']) ){}
```

---

If you want to keep the anchor (I advice against it), you can use javascript to fake the submit for you:

```
document.getElementById('yourAnchor').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('yourForm').submit();
}
// Or if you have jQuery:
$('#yourAnchor').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: or using JQuery
$(".submit").on("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("form").submit()
};

Comment: I've added a jquery version as well, slightly better (note the `closest()`)

Answer (score 1):

The submit button you are using is pointing towards the same url, can you try something like?

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and then try to see if the form is submitted from PHP.
And i also would recommend that you use some framework for this to handle sql injections and/or other exploits.

Comment: i use ci this was a project i was supposed to do changes , actually i  forgot to do it in custom because of  doing with ci and laravel since so long :D

Comment: ci is perfect for this, https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

Wrong use of form submit.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" style=" background: #eee; width:100px;display: block;margin-left:auto;">Submit</a>
 </div>
```

You should use it like:-

```
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" style="background: #eee; width:100px;display: block;margin-left:auto;" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

Hopefully this will solve the issue.